# Enable access to the Case object for Users with the Salesforce Platform license

Tags: case, licenses

We developed a solution based on the Case object but now some users with the Salesforce Platform license also need to use that feature. I just would like to know if there is any way to enable access to the Case object for Users with the Salesforce Platform license. Any ideas?

Comment: It does not appear to be possible with standard functionality, it might require a work around as they can use custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

No, Salesforce platform users cant access to Case object. There is no work around because it is the standard limitations of license type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: Employee Case

To Enable Employee Case, navigate to Users>Permission Sets>New Permission Set

Create a Permission set and assign the Customer Community Permission
After doing so, add object permissions for Case in that permission set, also set Tab visibility.
Now assign the permission set to your Platform Users.

Et voila

Comment: lol wat? Is this really working?

Comment: This did **not** work for me

Answer (score 0):

For Lightning Platform Starter licenses, using cases for customer service purposes, even internally, requires a Service Cloud license according to the [Platform license details documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&type=5).

In the Details under Cases, the documentation notes that both the Lightning Platform Starter and the Lightning Platform Plus licenses allow for full CRED access to Case object records...

[image: Case CRED Access for Lightning Platform Licenses]

With the citation references to specifics on both reading as follows:

[image: Citations on Case CRED Access for Lightning Platform Licenses]

However, there is a [Salesforce Knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354907&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) giving step by step instructions on how to grant users with Salesforce Platform License access to the Case object. Said article details that a permission set on the Company Community for Force.com permission set license must be created and Case CRED access can be granted through this method:

1. Navigate to Setup
2. Navigate to Permission Sets
3. Create new Permission Set
4. Enter the permission set's label of your choosing
5. Select the license Company Community for Force.com
6. Save
7. Navigate to Object Settings on newly created permission set
8. Navigate to Object Settings
9. Navigate to Cases
10. Click Edit
11. Specify permissions on the Case object
12. Save
13. Assign newly created permission set to Lightning Platform licensed users

We were able to successfully implement Case access for Lightning Platform Starter licensed users through the steps outlined without assigning full Service Cloud licenses to said users, so I suspect the Platform License Details documentation which states one must do so is out of date.

Should note one more thing: many Admins implementing the Lightning Platform licenses miss the step of assigning the Company Community for Force.com permission set license to all Lightning Platform licensed users, as this permission set license grants the mass of permissions that make Lightning Platform licenses feasible in the first place.

[image: Company Community for Force.com Permission Set License]

Comment: Thanks for the best practice, will modify my response to more thoroughly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SF Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354907&type=1) you could get access to Case object for Salesforce Platform license.
[image]